# SQL column name with comma

Tags: sql, oracle, quoted-identifier

im creating a csv file from sql and i must have column title name with comma 
like:

```
id,name,company
1,ART,Oracle

select ( id || ',' || name || ',' || company ) as **????????** from emplo
```

is there any way to display a sql column title with commas?

Comment: Use a _delimited identifier_, just like `as "a, b, c" from ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `"` to contain your column name.

```
select ( id || ',' || name || ',' || company )  "id,name,company" 
from emplo
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the reason for having a comma in column name, but its likely to only cause problems in parsing SQL statements in the future.

Check this document out...

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm